# Can I run a .net core app with non-core dependencies on a different OS?

Tags: c#, build, .net-core, dependencies, cross-platform

I am new to .NET Core Framework. I am building a .NET Core 2.0 console application that references the following two dependencies:

- System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager built for .NET Framework 4.5 downloaded from NuGet.
- A project from the same solution which is a .NET Framework 4.5 class library project

Since the Core Framework is cross-platform, I want to publish the application and run it on Linux. Should it work even though the two dependencies are not build for .NET Core? Or do I have to care during development that all of my dependencies are explicitly published for .NET Core?

In other words: Is a .NET Core app only cross-platform portable if all of it's dependencies are .NET Core?

Comment: Why use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` in the first place, when a .NET Core Console application can use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration to read from multiple sources, including xml and json files? What are you *really* trying to do with that library? Does your class library project load its settings from an app.config perhaps? Even then, you wouldn't need `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` unless you tried to load settings by key

Comment: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager is just an example. I might take as well any other library from NuGet. What I want to know is do I have to take care that every library I use must be a Core library and also port large amounts of self-written code to Core.

Comment: Most NuGet packages, especially from Microsoft are *.NET Standard* so they can be used by both frameworks. BTW the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` NuGet package itself is .NET Standard, so yes it can be used by Core. Your libraries should target .NET Standard if you want to use them from both Core and Full Framework

Comment: "just an example" creates more confusion here. 1) If you *can* convert your class library projects to .NET Standard, you should do so. Almost all NuGet package authors have migrated to .NET Standard. This ensures the least pain.

Comment: 2) A .NET Standard 2.0 or Core 2.0 project *can* reference a Full Framework library. Check [Reference .NET Framework libraries from .NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/). This is provided as a migration scenario though - Full Framework classes may not work on Linux because they can't find the runtime or OS calls they need. As the announcement says `This feature helps you migrate .NET Framework code to .NET Standard or .NET Core over time (start with binaries and then move to source).`

Comment: The answer to your last question is clear, that all dependencies must be tested for cross platform, which in your case does not seem to be.